# Cannot start a service from another application with "not found" error

Tags: android, android-service

There are two apps, first one has a service and can start it. Second one tries to start the service from the first app and cannot because the service is "not found". I believe that the service is enabled and exported (see code below). What's wrong?

The manifest of the first app with declaration of the service:

```
<manifest ...
    package="com.example.fooapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application ...>
        <service
            android:name=".FooService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" ...>
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

From that application I can start the `FooService` by the following commands:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.fooapplication", "com.example.fooapplication.FooService"));
Log.d("happy", "FooApplication " + intent);
startService(intent);
```

It works, there is the log (two last lines are from the service itself):

```
12-19 10:18:58.520 12869 12869 D happy   : FooApplication Intent { cmp=com.example.fooapplication/.FooService }
12-19 10:18:58.568 12869 12869 D happy   : FooService constructor
12-19 10:18:58.568 12869 12869 D happy   : FooService onCreate
```

The same code sequence at the second app cannot start that service:

```
12-19 10:31:22.300 13644 13644 D happy   : BarApplication Intent { cmp=com.example.fooapplication/.FooService }
12-19 10:31:22.301  1712  3872 W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.example.fooapplication/.FooService } U=0: not found
```

Building parameters for both applications are:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Device with Android 12 (SDK 31)

Comment: Does the other app have the `<queries>` manifest element to deal with [package visibility rules](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring)?

Comment: @CommonsWare no, and that's the reason, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is in "package visibility" introduced by Android 11 (SDK 30).
https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

The manifest at the second app (which is not owner of the service) should contain:

```
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.example.fooapplication" />
    </queries>
```

Thanks to @CommonsWare